# What are the properties and methods which could be accessed in Dictionary<TKey, TValue> rather than IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Is there a properties or methods which i could not perform using IDictionary object, where as it can be performed using Dictionary.

The other differences for the Dictionary and IDictionary are present in the below link.

[A difference in style: IDictionary vs Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595498/a-difference-in-style-idictionary-vs-dictionary)

[What is the difference between dictionary(Of String, String) and IDictionary(Of String, String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724537/what-is-the-difference-between-dictionaryof-string-string-and-idictionaryof)

[IDictionary<string, string> versus Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328830/idictionarystring-string-versus-dictionarystring-string)

I want to know what are all the properties and methods which are exposed under Dictionary, and hidden under IDictionary.

Thanks in Advance,

Arun

Comment: I think you'll find the best answer by comparing their pages on the msdn website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the differences you can simply compare them on MSDN. Those other links aren't the definitions of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, they're other questions related to them. The source of the **definition** of these things lives on MSDN.

[Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)
[IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are a number of differences that you'll see. For example methods inherited from `System.Object` such as `GetHashCode()` and `ToString()`. The `Dictionary` is also serializable so has some methods to help with that, which the `IDictionary` doesn't define. You'll need to look at those and consider if they're important to determine whether you use the interface for a contract, or the Dictionary.